# How to go to nextactivity after login with facebook account

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-intent

I did log in using Facebook account by importing `Facebook sdk` as library in my android app but the main problem is i want to go to another activity when i do log in with Facebook account i am not understanding how to do this.

**LoginActivity.java :**

```
public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {




private ProgressDialog pDialog;

Button btn_login,bnt_Register ;
EditText edt_email,edt_password;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();



private static String url_create_product = "http://192.168.1.6/laravel/public/user";


private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
//private static final String TAG_PORTFOLIOS = "lists";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    bnt_Register=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btn_login =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    edt_email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
    edt_password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);


    bnt_Register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,AccountRegister.class);
            startActivity(in);



        }


    });



    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new EmailPassword().execute();



        }
    });





}



class EmailPassword extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String email =edt_email.getText().toString();
     String password =edt_password.getText().toString();


     List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
     params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

     try{
     JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params1);


     Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

    return json.toString();
     }catch(Exception e){}



        return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
         try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(file_url);
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);


                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // closing this screen
                //finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    }


@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();

  // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
  AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
}
@Override


protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();

  // Logs 'app deactivate' App Event.
  AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
}


}
```

Comment: i Update your question code please check it.

Answer (score 0):

you should do that in `onPostExecute` method. set a flag for response for example set a boolean to true if login was successful and start your other activity in `onPostExecute` method if `flag == true` .

Answer (score 0):

change your Post execute method:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog once done
    pDialog.dismiss();
    Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,YourActivity.class);
    startActivity(in);
}
```

Comment: this is not working for me. After fill the log in information in  facebook i got this error "App not setup. The developers  of this app  have not setup  this app properly for the facebook login"